# Backend only alternative to javascript periodic function call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I have the following in my js file that is included in the main .cshtml page of my ASP.NET MVC application:

```
var ajax_call = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "/Session/Index/",
        success: function (result) {
            if (!(result.length > 0)) {

                window.location.href = '/Home/Index/'
            }

        }
    });


};

var interval = 1000 * 60 * .2; // where X is your every X minutes---.2 -> every 12 seconds

setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```

The goal is to check if the session is still valid (the SessionController only returns a result if the session is active), otherwise the browser gets redirected to Home/Index, where HomeController has a global authorization attribute that redirects to the login page if the log in is not a valid session.

My questions are, is this a valid approach? It works (if I login in with a user, then open a new window and log in with the same user in the new window, the old window gets redirected to the login screen shortly after, depending on where it is in the 12 second cycle), but is there a way I can do such a thing entirely in the backend?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can't force a redirect from the backend.  But you can redirect the user to the login page on their next request from the backend.  Isn't that what the authorization system would already do anyway though?

Comment: I a assuming you are posting a "token" that was set in the cookies somehow, the backend auth module should have some way to expire that token, (you could base that expiricy on the duplicity of the session) and then redirect him to the main page without a valid token anymore like "0000"

Comment: @David yes that is what the system does, but I am trying to get it to do it periodically, by performing a request every 12 seconds. Basically, I am trying to simulate a request to the backend.

Comment: @ITWorker: In that case your options are either this polling approach or perhaps a web sockets approach (likely using SignalR) which would "push" to the page in response to a server-side event.  This would be more complex of course, but it would also get rid of that 12-second window.  Basically as soon as Window 2 logs in as the user and invalidates the server-side session, that server-side code would send a message to the JavaScript code in Window 1 which could immediately redirect the user.

Comment: @AlejandroVales I am not doing anything with tokens, the SessionController page just has an index page that gets returned only when a session is active, and the way a session check is done is by modifying and checking data in the database regarding logged in sessions.

Comment: @David I will look into SignalR, but according to your response ("...send a message to the JavaScript code in Window 1"), it sounds that approach would require some javascript as well. Is there no way to do it without any frontend involvement?

Comment: @ITWorker: No, there is no way to redirect the browser without involving the browser.  Either the user has to initiate an action, or client-side code needs to initiate an action.

Comment: @ITWorker: If you intend to develop for the web, you should really familiarize yourself with the protocols that it works off of, namely HTTP. Amongst other things, HTTP utilizes a request-response model: a client makes a request, and the server responds, in that order. SignalR blurs the lines a bit, but the fundamental idea remains. If you want info from the server, the client must initiate it.

Comment: @David ok thanks, I was thinking about Gmail when I began working with this functionality. I remember I logged in to multiple tabs, and when I signed out in one tab, a few seconds later, the other tab signed out as well. This isn't exactly the same as my scenario, but similar I think.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes I understand the basics of HTTP, but I wanted to see if a back-end only solution existed because I kept reading/hearing that validation of any type on the frontend also needs to happen in the back end for security reasons. I considered session checking as a validation, and I had got it working via the frontend means.

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is to check if the session is still valid

This is not a good approach, because ***a request to a server will rest the session timeout to 0***. *It means you are making session alive forever.* If a user forgets to close the browser and leave the computer open, other can still access the account.

Here is the approach I use in my websites *inspired by banking/credit card websites.*

By default, Session Time out is 20 minutes *(you can adjust the way you want)*. So, I let timer run at client side. When it reaches 19 minutes, I display a popup message with a minute count down timer.

[image]

If use does not close the popup, I redirect to logout page.

[Here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/notification/examples/sessiontimeout/defaultcs.aspx) is the concept and sample code, but you do not need to use Telerik control to achieve it.

Comment: This scenario is slightly different, but it will be helpful when I get to session timeouts. My question was about kicking out a user in one window when he/she logs in from another window.

Comment: If that is the case, you can use your original approach, because the browser's session is invalid when the ajax request is performed.